# variable "_method" is not defined in s3demo.php

Tags: fine-uploader

I am using fine uploader. for the server side handling using s3demo.php,(downloaded from github).

But while sending response to this file, there are error that, $_POST['_method'] is not defined.

can any body give me solution for this problem ?

Comment: Show your client side code

Comment: Also, what version of php, and what specific request or requests are failing?

Comment: Are uploads failing, or is this just a warning from the interpreter? Which server are you using? I believe this is related to [issue #27](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader-server/issues/27), a fix is linked to in that issue.